# How do I achieve this output in a Google Data Studio report, given the raw data?

Tags: looker-studio

I have a small set of test records in Google Data Studio and am attempting to create a table that gives me breakdowns of particular values relative to the total number of values, by dimension.  I think the image here below describes the need clearly.  I have tried using an approach I saw online entailing creating a calculated field like this:

case when Action = 'Clicked' then 1 else 0 end

and then creating a metric based upon that field, which does the 'Percentage of Total - Relative to Corresponding Data' but this produces incorrect numbers and seems really cumbersome (needing one calculated field per distinct value).  My client wants this exact tabular presentation, not a chart(s).

How do I achieve the desired report?

[image: Details:]

Thanks!

Comment: ... And what's your question exactly?

Comment: I'm showing my desired report output.  I'm trying to get that in a tabular visualization.  How do I achieve that output with the given raw data input?  I don't know how else to explain it.

Answer (score 1):

Solution entails creating fields like 'Opened' which outputs 1 when Action = 'Opened', 0 otherwise.  Then create fields like 'Opened Rate' with e.g. sum(Opened) / Record Count.  Then set those as percentages.